# How to disable highlighting when an item is disabled in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I am a WPF newbie.  I have a list of checkboxes in a listview in WPF.  I have functionality where when the user clicks on the checkbox, it highlights the row.  All that is working fine.  However, when checkbox is disabled, it still highlights the row and it also checks the checkbox.  How do I make it so it does not highlight or check when the user clicks a disabled checkbox?  Thanks in advance.

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="lstRewardsExpiration_ScrollChanged" Height="178" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,81" Name="lstRewardsEarned" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="327" SelectionMode="Multiple" Background="White" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Cyan"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I don't see any checkboxes in the code you posted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to use a `MultiTrigger` to get this to work

Here is an example if I read your question correctly

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />

    <!-- bind content IsEnabled to the ListViewItem IsEnabled -->
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border x:Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <!--Highlight if IsSelected and IsEnabled-->
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Cyan"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <!--Remove highlight if is not Selected and IsEnabled-->
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <!--Add a trigger to remove the higlighting if IsEnabled is changed to false-->
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```